# How do I run a VBA function after a field is filled? (Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

After the user enters in a JobNumber, I want it to autorun a script to retrieve JobNames, and other information. Would I be able to do this through a macro to call the VBA function? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You do this in the `AfterUpdate` event of the text box. Create an event procedure and enter your code there.

Comment: Is the AfterUpdate a macro command or do I write this from VBA?

Comment: The AfterUpdate calls my macro, however, my macro never runs under any conditions, It only runs when i manually run it.

Comment: Then you will have to adjust your macro.